# What is the state-level / region-level equivalent for "federalize"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Let's say some government function is currently controlled on the local level. (For example, in the USA, most K-12 schools are controlled locally.)

If a federal government were to centralize control on the federal level, it would "federalize" that control.

If a federal government were to decentralize control on the local level, it would "localize" that control.

What is the equivalent for governments between "local" and "national", such as state governments in the USA?

- In Canada one might say "provincial control" and "[provincialize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provincialize) control".
- In general, one might say "regional control" or "regionalize control" (though "regionalize" is more commonly used for "combining local agencies into one, below the state/province level").
- But "state control" implies public/government control (not private/firm control), while ["statealize"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22statealize%22) is not a word.

Relevant previous questions: ["Federal" is to "Federally" as "State" is to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521572/federal-is-to-federally-as-state-is-to) and ["What's a word or phrase for something government-level or state-level?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349665/whats-a-word-or-phrase-for-something-government-level-or-state-level)

Comment: Best option is probably to rewrite with terms like "state-wide" or "at state level". Although maybe someone can find a rarer verb.

Comment: I would have thought *regionalize* means moving things/power/decisions up or down to the regional level

Comment: 'Statal' is the rare adjective meaning 'of/pertaining to a state', but 'statalise' (try googling) had a specific meaning perhaps not really applicable here.

Comment: To centralize control to the city level, you would use "municipalize".  Maybe there is a word to replace "state" in the same way that "municipal" replaces "city".

Comment: Are you asking for a word for regulation which is no longer federal but now state-regulated, or for a word for regulation which was local but is now regulated at a higher level (like the state)? That is, is control being **raised** similar to *federalize* or **lowered** similar to *devolve*?

Comment: At the risk of opinion, a chain of UK governments has made such a mess of the system that it is hard to say whether it is local or national.

Answer (score 1):

*If a federal government were to decentralize control <strike>**on**</strike> **to** the local level, it would "**devolve**" that control.*

> **devolve**  [<sub><sup>(definedictionarymeaning.com)</sup></sub>](https://definedictionarymeaning.com/topic/16470/devolve/2)
> *Transfer or delegate (power) **to a lower level**, especially from central government to local or regional administration.*

Comment: @FumbeFingers:  Yes, that is just the word, though, as per my comment, the setting up of privately governed academies has left us with a virtually anarchic mix of 'local authority', central and neither.

Comment: We have the same issues in the UK. People tend to forget that one of the driving forces behind *centralising* authority is the depressing regularity with which we see corruption in local government. Sure, we get corruption in central government too - but at least with national / international media we're more likely to *discover* corruption in the White House than in some sleepy village parish council.

Comment: @ Fumble Fingers:  This is getting near the knuckle of politics.  I think I'll depart in peace.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a word not often found in the past, but with in entry ins some dictionaries. It's the word "*defederalize*".

([Examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22defederalize%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/defederalize))
> **defederalize**
> to shift the functions or powers of (an agency, service, etc.) from the jurisdiction of the federal government to that of state or local government

Comment: Is it asking too much of the downvoter to drop a word in the comment space for the reason of his "-1"?